# Identity Server Getting "error": "invalid_scope"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am getting error while trying to get token for my custom scope value.Below is My code snippet.

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis() =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
             new ApiResource("ApiOne","ApiOne",new []{ "ApiOne"})
        };
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
        new List<Client> { new Client
        {
            ClientId="client1",
            ClientSecrets={ new Secret("secret1".Sha256())},
            AllowedGrantTypes={GrantType.ClientCredentials},
            AllowedScopes={"ApiOne"},
            AllowOfflineAccess=true,
            
        },
        };
```

Comment: What's your client configuration?

Comment: Are you defining scope for API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add ApiScope in configuration

```
public static List<ApiScope> Get()
    {
        return new List<ApiScope>
       {
           new ApiScope
           {
               Name = "ApiOne",
               Emphasize=true,
           },
           new ApiScope
           {
               Name = "ApiTwo",
               Emphasize=true,
           },
       };
    }
```

In Startup file add

```
.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configuration.Get());
```